# Velocity, Wave Equation, Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose you have a differential equation of the form:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} = C \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} + D \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$

Is it possible to find the velocity from this?

For a normal wave equation:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} = C \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}
$$

The velocity would be given by:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}$$

Is it possible to identify the velocity in the former case?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67338/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a candidate solution of the form $u=x(z)e^{i\omega t}$. Solve the simplified ordinary differential equation. What can you conclude about the velocity?

**EDIT:** You'll get the following equation

$$\frac{d^2x}{dz^2} + (\omega^2~C - i \omega D) x = 0$$

which has solutions

$$x=A e^{imx} + B e^{-imx}$$

with $m=\sqrt{\omega^2~C - i \omega D}$. The point now is computing the real part of $m$ because that's the wave number $k$. The imaginary part corresponds to an exponential attenuation term.

**EDIT 2** After some work, you should get that

$$k=\mathcal{Re(m)}=\omega\sqrt{\frac{C+\sqrt{D^2\omega^{-2}+C^2}}{2}}$$

or rearranging

$$v=\frac{\omega}{k}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{C+\sqrt{D^2\omega^{-2}+C^2}}}$$

which teaches us that the speed is now frequency dependent. This phenomenon is called dispersion and is introduced by the term linear in the derivative w.r.t. $t$.

Comment: In this case, you would get:

$$
\frac{d^2~x}{dz^2} = - \omega^2~C x + i \omega D x
$$

Since this part is complex, does that just mean the velocity wont be affected by this additional term?

Comment: You forgot a factor $x$ on your right hand side. You should get a wave with an exponential attenuation term. Find the speed of the wave with the usual $\omega/k=v$ rule. The point is finding what $k$ is.

Comment: If you do what you suggest, you would get:

$$
\frac{d^2~x}{dz^2} = - k^2~v^2~C x + i k~v~D x
$$

How does finding $k$ help you determine $v$? Also, what about if $k$ is complex?

Comment: You misunderstood what I suggested. See my edit.

Comment: What is we use a solution of the form $K e^{i(kz - \omega t)}$. How do we get velocity information from this?

Comment: You can do that as well, but you should be aware that the $k$ in your knew formula will have a real and an imaginary part. Only the real part will give information about velocity. The $k$ in your formula is the $m$ in mine.